# Port forwarding to webserver - still redirects to local IP address

Tags: linux, http, port-forwarding

I'm extremely new at unix/linux so please bear that in mind in your answer.

I am running an apache server on a Fedora box. I have a static IP and have set up port forwarding through my router/modem - I have opened up port 80, among others, to forward to my Fedora box.

If, from an outside connection, I type my static IP, I successfully get my index page. However, if I try to type my.static.ip/subdirectory this gets instantly replaced with 192.168.2.22/subdirectory (my LAN IP), which of course fails if I'm on an outside connection.

Why is this remapping happening? How can I set up my server such that this remapping doesn't occur when requesting sub-pages/sub-directories from an external connection (while still working correctly if I connect to my local ip from a local LAN connection)?

Comment: I suspect you're actually trying to access http://1.2.3.4/subdir (without trailing slash) and it redirects you to http://192.168.1.1/subdir/ (with trailing slash). I had this once, but I don't remember how I fixed this, so currently, I can't answer it for you. But this bit of information is relevant for people asking your question. You might want to edit the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to adjust the [UseCanonicalName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname) and [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#servername) settings in your configuration. Either in your httpd.conf file, or in your virtual host definition file.

I believe you want to have

```
UseCanonicalName Off
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! For others who are noobs like me, you'll find httpd.conf here /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf